# How to start Viber on system boot?

Tags: startup, viber

I cannot make Viber to start on system boot. In the Viber settings I've checked: Start Viber on system startup. This seems to have added entry in the start up applications with command: viber. However such command does not exist. Tried to locate the installation with command whereis, but...

```
yasen@yasen-TECRA-Z50-A:~$ whereis viber
viber: /usr/share/viber
yasen@yasen-TECRA-Z50-A:/usr/share/viber$ ll
total 52
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 13 23:03 ./
drwxr-xr-x 327 root root 12288 Dec  6 19:00 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  3957 Oct 31  2013 128x128.png
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   547 Oct 31  2013 16x16.png
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   867 Oct 31  2013 24x24.png
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  8001 Oct 31  2013 256x256.png
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1091 Oct 31  2013 32x32.png
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1573 Oct 31  2013 48x48.png
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2043 Oct 31  2013 64x64.png
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2961 Oct 31  2013 96x96.png
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to startup applications -

[image]

Click on the **Add** button -

[image]

and fill out the fields in the following manner -

[image]

> Name: Viber
>
> Command: /opt/viber/Viber
>
> Comment: Connect. Freely.

Alternatively, you can create a symbolic link between the `.desktop` file created by the method suggested by αғsнιη and */etc/xdg/autostart/* -

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/Viber.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/
```

Comment: /opt/viber/Viber this is what I needed. Thanks a lot to both answers.

Comment: Lamy, you started a bounty on this and it looks like the answer Rohith gave you solved your problem. You should accept his answer so he gets the bounty you set.

Answer (score 4):

#### GUI method:

You can achieve what you want by going to the *Startup Application* Preferences from dash and create a NEW startup item. Just click on the Add button, which brings up an input dialog. In that dialog, you specify a name to call it, an optional comment blurb, and the command to execute(will be `/opt/viber/Viber`), which would be the path of Viber. When you're done, a new `NAME.desktop` file will appear in `~/.config/autostart`.

#### CLI method:

or you can create that .desktop file by your hand. (Advanced users using this method)

Create a `Viber.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart/` and copy&paste the the following content in it and save.

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/viber/Viber
Hidden=false
Name=Viber
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

You can create/edit `Viber.desktop` file by `gedit ~/.config/autostart/Viber.desktop` in Terminal.

Done. Logoff and login back to see the changes.

---

As documentation [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html), the Startup Applications are `.desktop` files stored per-user in:

```
~/.config/autostart
```

And also globally, for all users, in:

```
/etc/xdg/autostart
```

(*Note that in KDE it's stored in `~/.kde/Autostart` directory.*)

The enable/disable feature is provided by this attribute in each `.desktop` file:

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true (or false)
```

If a user toggles enable/disable status of a given application (without deleting it) that was in the system folder, it is copied to the user directory and then the attribute `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled` is changed. If a user deletes a given application from the list, the .desktop is copied to user folder with the `Hidden=true` attribute (or the file is simply deleted if it was present just in the user directory)